# CakePHP 2.5 Datasource, create and return response

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, datasource

I have a specific task to connect CakePHP web application to a remote restful server . I create a datasource, read method works great, but the api after save data return an array of processed data.

Looking for a way to return the data array and use in controller.

**My Controller code**

```
public function admin_generate()
{
    $data = $this->request->data;   
    $data['path'] = 'special/generate';
    $this->Tool->create();
    if($this->Tool->save($data)){
      // handle response ????
    }
    $this->set('data',$data);
    $this->set('_serialize','data');

}
```

**In datasource file**

```
    public function create(Model $model, $fields = null, $values = null)
    {
    $data = array_combine($fields, $values);
    $api = $this->config['api_path'].$data['path'].'?auth_key='.$this->config['auth_key'];

    $json = $this->Http->post($api, $data);

    $response = json_decode($json, true);
    if (is_null($response)) {
        $error = json_last_error();
        throw new CakeException($error);
    }
    return $response; // ??????
    }
```

Can someone show me the correct way to use the api response data in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, a few minutes after a post question. This can help one of you.

**datasource**

```
....

if (is_null($response)) {
    $error = json_last_error();
    throw new CakeException($error);
}
// SOLUTION
$model -> code = $response['code'];
$model -> key = $response['key'];
$model -> code_id = $response['code_id'];
return true;
.....
```

**in controller**

```
.....
if($this->Tool->save($data)){
        unset($data['path']);
        $data['code'] = $this->Tool->code;
        $data['key'] = $this->Tool->key;
        $data['code_id'] = $this->Tool->code_id;
    }
.....
```